# Using a colormap for a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have pandas series of complex numbers, which I would like to plot. Currently, I am looping through each point and assigning it a color. I would prefer to generate the plot without the need to loop over each point... Using `Series.plot()` would be preferable. Converting series to numpy is ok though.

Here is an example of what I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

s = pd.Series((1+np.random.randn(500)*0.05)*np.exp(1j*np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 500)))

cmap = pyplot.cm.viridis    
for i, val in enumerate(s):
    pyplot.plot(np.real(val), np.imag(val), 'o', ms=10, color=cmap(i/(len(s)-1)))
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: how to get rid of the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pyplot.scatter`, which allows coloring of points based on a value.

```
pyplot.scatter(np.real(s), np.imag(s), s=50, c=np.arange(len(s)), cmap='viridis')
```

Here, we set `c` to an increasing sequence to get the same result as in the question.
[image]

Comment: Thanks!! exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply plot the real and imaginary part of the series without a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series((1+np.random.randn(500)*0.05)*np.exp(1j*np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 500)))

plt.plot(s.values.real,s.values.imag, marker="o", ls="")

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, you need to use a scatter plot if you want to have different colors:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series((1+np.random.randn(500)*0.05)*np.exp(1j*np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 500)))

plt.scatter(s.values.real,s.values.imag, c = range(len(s)), cmap=plt.cm.viridis)

plt.show()
```

[image]